# Passing values from fragment to Activity

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I have in my Fragment a view holder (with data fetched from URL JSON) but the issue is I get Null Exception most likley due to the passed string being empty or *null* even though I gets set from the JSON in the fragment.

**My Fragment - ViewHolder - Works from JSON URL**

```
   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView field_image_thumb;
    public TextView field_name;
    //public TextView updated;
    public View statusCurrent;
    public TextView statusText;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        field_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_name);
        //updated = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.updated);
        statusText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        statusCurrent = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusCurrent);
        field_image_thumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_image_thumb);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FieldActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(FieldActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());

                //Pass simple string to activity
                intent.putExtra("field_name", itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_name).toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
```

**My Activity onCreate - trying to get string passed**

```
//set string from fragment..
String field_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("field_name");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.field_activity_detail);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    // Set title of Detail page
    // collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.item_title));

    int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);

    //Set Title but get Null due to data not being passed correctly from fragment
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(field_name);

    //...
    //...

    }
```

Not sure why the field_name string is not passed to the activity

Comment: You can't call `getIntent()` there. Move the `field_name` assignment to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes I have now done that, but getting raw android code being passed to the field_name and not the string value in the fragment

Comment: `itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_name).toString()` - You're calling `toString()` on a `View`. If you want the text of a `TextView`, you need to cast that `View` to `TextView`, and call `getText().toString()` on that.

Comment: Thanks @Mike M - I used intent.putExtra("field_name", field_name.getText().toString()); and correct data coming through